# help - sed - insert space between any string of form XxxXxx, without replacing the pattern

Tags: shell, unix, sed, design-patterns

If the string is of the pattern **XxxXyzAbc...**
The expected out put from sed has to be **Xxx Xyz Abc ...**

eg: if the string is **QcfEfQfs**, then the expected output is **Qcf Ef Efs.**

If i try to substitute the pattern **[a-z][A-Z]** with space then the sed will replace the character or pattern with space, like **Qc f fs.**

Is there any way to insert space in between without replacing the pattern ?.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use match groups.

```
$ sed 's/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/g' <<< 'XxxXyzAbc'
Xxx Xyz Abc
```

Answer (score 0):

A more accurate pattern match - one with fewer spurious matches on strings that are not in the XxxYyyZzz format - is:

```
sed 's/\([A-Z][a-z][a-z]*\)\([A-Z][a-z][a-z]*\)\([A-Z][a-z][a-z]*\)/\1 \2 \3/'
```

Consider the inputs:

```
XxxYyyZzz
xxxYyyZzz
X xY yZ z
```

One other answer I see will insert spaces in all the strings - when it should only modify the first string.

Updated to allow for the `QcfEfEfs` example - it isn't clear from the question how many lower case letters in a row are allowed.  It could be 1 or 2; or it could be 1 or more - using a `*` allows for 1 or more; otherwise, use `\{1,2\}` for 1 or 2.

Comment: You're missing a closing square bracket. Your command fails on the OP's "QcfEfQfs".

Comment: @Dennis: drat - yup.  I fixed it in the version I tested; and forgot to change the code before adding answer.  Bother  And yes, I missed the QcfEfEfs example...I wonder how many lower-case letters in a row...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B[[:upper:]]/ &/g' file
```

Looks for a non-word boundary followed by an uppercase character and inserts a space throughout the line.